# algoritmo que me calcule la velocidad promedio de los pedidos que fueron entregados

Tags: java

Tengo que desarrollar un algoritmo que me calcule la velocidad promedio de los pedidos que fueron entregados. Ésta se calcula en base a los tiempos de producción y a la cantidad de unidades que posee cada pedido; pero éstas se toman en cuenta de acuerdo a una fecha historia entregada por el usuario desde la cual se empezaran a considerar los pedidos para el cálculo.

Resulta que todos los datos provienen de un archivo Excel, por lo que se leen en `double`, pero al hacer correr el programa me arroja un error "NaN" (not a number), no entiendo cuál es el problema. Adjunto parte del código

Método clase pedido para cálculo de velocidad:

```
public double CalcularVelocidadL1(Date fechaHist){
    llenarLista();//metodo que me llena la lista en la que voy a trabajar
    double suma=0;
    int cont=0;
    NodoListaL1 aux= headL1;
    while(aux.getNext()!=null){
        if(aux.getNext().getDato().getFec_ped().after(fechaHist)||  aux.getNext().getDato().getFec_ped().equals(fechaHist)){
            double num=aux.getNext().getDato().getUni_lot();
            double den=aux.getNext().getDato().getTmp_proc();
            double div=num/den;
            suma=suma+div;
            cont++;
        }
    }
    aux=aux.getNext();
    double vel=(suma/cont);
    return vel;
}
```

Método main donde se pide la fecha:

```
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException, ParseException{
    BufferedReader lector=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    LeerExcel excel=new LeerExcel();
    excel.Leer();

    System.out.println("ingrese fecha");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String f=lector.readLine();
    Date fecha=sdf.parse(f);

    ArraylistP v =new ArraylistP();
    double d=v.CalcularVelocidadL1(fecha);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: Que mensaje se muestra en la consola? Que fecha introduces?

Comment: ingreso una fecha menor a la que esta en el excel. en excel la mayor fecha es 09/01/2013 y yo ingreso por ejemplo 02/01/2"013 y muestra "NaN

Comment: No me queda claro, ¿en qué línea falla?

Comment: @sebastian siempre que realices una pregunta no olvides agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en la consola, de esta manera te pueden  ayudar con más rapidez y exactitud, de otra forma tu pregunta puede considerarse como "muy amplia" =(

Comment: El archivo en excel que extensión tiene y por medio de que libreria esta haciendo la lectura?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que se esta leyendo como numero algo que es texto en el Excel pero sin mas información no podemos saber mas.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente tienes un problema XY. Es decir, tu síntoma es un NAN y preguntas por eso, pero tu problema es otro. Concrétamente el `getNext()`

En tu pregunta no pones la clase `NodoListaL1` por lo que no sabemos qué hace. Esto dificulta el responderte. Al formular una pregunta es mejor poner un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Que en este caso debiera incluir la clase NodoListaL1 y posiblemente `LeerExcel`. Quítale todo lo que puedas quitar, para que sea mínimo. Pero el programa debe poder ejecutarse y mostrar el error. Incluye también un enlace a un Excel de prueba.

Aún faltando elementos para responderte es fácil imaginar que la función `getNext()` devuelve un elemento y avanza un contador interno de forma que sucesivas llamadas devuelva elementos posteriores. Pero presumiblemente tu quieres tratar el mismo elemento en cada iteración del bucle. En tal caso quieres un bucle tal que así:

```
NodoListaL1 aux= headL1;
for(;;)
{
  AlgunTipo elemento;
  elemento = aux.getNext();
  if (elemento==null)
    break;
  if(elemento.getDato().getFec_ped().after(fechaHist)||  elemento.getDato().getFec_ped().equals(fechaHist)){
      double num=elemento.getDato().getUni_lot();
      double den=elemento.getDato().getTmp_proc();
      double div=num/den;
      suma=suma+div;
      cont++;
  }
}
```

Aunque también es posible que tengas un problema XXY. Es decir, que tengas 2 problemas, lo del NAN y lo del `getNext()`. Con una pregunta con los elementos que indico anteriormente sería posible discernir esto.